# Firebase's snapshot.value cast to Bool suddenly returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

So my code was working perfectly fine but today it is returning nil when I try to cast Firebase's snapshot.value to a Bool. I haven't made any change to code at all. But it works fine if I cast it to a String (as? String returns "true").

Same issue at another place where I was casting to [String: Bool].

One thing that is different from earlier, I installed Xcode 10 beta 3 today (Xcode 9.4 is installed too). Both Xcode versions are returning nil. Here's the code:

```
if let currentUserId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid{

        Database.database().reference().child("users/\(currentUserId)/share").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

            let data = snapshot.value as? Bool

            if data == true{

                self.showNotificationsBadge()

            }

        }

    }
```

**Edit:** Snapshot is not nil. You can see that in the console pane. I have printed both snapshot.key and .value.

**Edit 2:** I'm sorry if my question caused any confusions. The main purpose of this question is to know the problem, is it Firebase SDK or Xcode. Because it was working perfectly till now. I know how I can tackle this and how can I convert a String to a Bool.

**Edit 3:** Thank you everyone for your answers. I'm sorry I was unable to deliver my thoughts correctly. I just want to know about this unpredicted behavior and why is it happening? Who is the culprit here? Xcode, Firebase SDK? This code worked PERFECTLY FINE for about a month. I'm not asking for a solution, I'm just curious about this behavior. It would be great if someone from team Firebase can explain this issue.

**Edit 4:** Removed image and added code. Also figured out the issue thanks to @Jay's comment.

Comment: Most likely, one of your nodes has something it in that isn't a Bool (e.g. "true" isn't a bool). Try commenting out the code in the closure and replacing it with a *print(snapshot)* and inspect the output in the console. In general, include a snippet of your Firebase structure in your question as well. Also, please do NOT include images in your questions. Include code and structures as text. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy an paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: ...and duplicated these findings; having a node of "true" instead of true causes the *data* var to be nil as expected.

Comment: I just posted image to show the code, debugger, and console at one place. You can see in the console I have printed out snapshot.key & .value. And value is true not "true".  But I got your point. I'll keep that in mind and won't post images.  Thanks for pointing to Firebase structure. I just figured out the problem. I was writing true as a Bool while our Android dev was doing it as a String.  But still curious why couldn't it convert an object containing true to Bool.  Anyway how could I accept your answer since it's a comment?

Comment: ...leaving link to the [image](https://imgur.com/lvcDu3W) since I've removed it from the question. You can see the snapshot value in console here.

Comment: Great! Glad you found the issue! No need to accept as it's a common issue folks run into.

Answer (score 1):

You need check if the snapshot is nil before checking the value.

```
if let data = snapshot.value as? Bool {
```

....
}

Comment: yes you are right I should check that first but you can see in the console I have printed snapshot.key and .value and neither is nil.

Comment: @Hadi Changed your code to "observing.value" and not "observing.childAdded". Try and let me know if works.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me just recently. I discovered that I had quotes around the child value, eg. "true". Remove the quotes and the solution from @Maximo should work as expected.